# GridView still being refreshed when not in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel

**Problem and Description:**

I have a GridView with programmatically added DropDownLists on `RowDataBound` to every cell.

The DropDownLists all have `Data Sources`.

When I press a 'Save' button, it is meant to read all the `selecteditems` in the DropDownLists and save them to a database.

However, when I click on the button, it causes `postback` and deletes all of the controls in the GridView and therefore, none of them can be found in my `button_click` event.

After asking questions before and trying different techniques to try store the dropdownlists in Cache/Session state etc, I simply can't seem to be able to keep the dropdownlists or the data when I click the button.

Therefore, I am now trying to add an UpdatePanel and use AJAX to try stop the refresh of the GridView.

My attempt was as such:

```
                         <asp:GridView ID="gv_Rota" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowDataBound="gv_Rota_RowDataBound">
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6a3d98" ForeColor="White" Height="20" />
                                    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="20px" Width="100px" />
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle Height="20px" />
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </div>

                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_NameOfRota" runat="server" Text="New rota name:"></asp:Label>
                            <input runat="server" id="txt_RotaName" />

                            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="RotaUpdatePanel">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_AddRota" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btn_AddRota_Click" CssClass="ButtonAdminPage" />
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

As you can see, I placed the UpdatePanel around my button only, however, it still seemed to refresh the GridView and delete all the controls.

**Questions:**

Firstly, why did my attempt not work?

Secondly, how can I get around this problem using AJAX and Update Panels, or is there another method to get me what I need? (Baring in mind, if something else is suggested, I've probably already tried it).

**EDIT 2:**

**Supplied Code:**

This is when I bind the DropDownLists:

```
 protected void gv_Rota_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                int day = e.Row.RowIndex;
                day += 1;
                ddlShift = new DropDownList();
                ddlShift.ID = "ddlShift" + "WK" + i.ToString() + "DAY" + day.ToString();
                ddlShift.DataSource = DCListOfShifts;
                ddlShift.DataValueField = "SHIFT_ID";
                ddlShift.DataTextField = "SHIFT_NAME";
                ddlShift.Attributes.Add("Place", i.ToString());
                ddlShift.DataBind();
                ddlShift.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Shift..."));
                ddlShift.CssClass = "ddl_rotamanager";
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(ddlShift);
            }
        }          
    }
```

This is when I create the GridView dependant on the amount of columns passed:

```
 private void BindGrid(int Amount)
    {
            gv_Rota.DataSource = null;
            gv_Rota.Columns.Clear();

        BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
        bfield.HeaderText = "Days";
        bfield.DataField = "Days";
        gv_Rota.Columns.Add(bfield);

        for (int i = 0; i < Amount; i++)
        {
            int week = i + 1;
            string sWeek = "Week " + week.ToString();

            TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
            tfield.HeaderText = sWeek;
            gv_Rota.Columns.Add(tfield);
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Days", typeof(string)));
        dt.Rows.Add("M");
        dt.Rows.Add("T");
        dt.Rows.Add("W");
        dt.Rows.Add("T");
        dt.Rows.Add("F");
        dt.Rows.Add("S");
        dt.Rows.Add("S");
        gv_Rota.DataSource = dt;
        gv_Rota.DataBind();

    }
```

This is where I get the selected amount of columns and call the method to create the GridView, I also store the amount in Cache:

```
protected void ddl_RotaAmountOfWeeks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            int Amount;
            int.TryParse(ddl_RotaAmountOfWeeks.SelectedItem.ToString(), out Amount);

            ColumnCount = Amount;

            Cache.Add("columnCount", ColumnCount, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0, 60, 0), CacheItemPriority.Default, null);

            BindGrid(Amount);
        }
    }
```

Button code:

```
 protected void btn_AddRota_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //My first attempt at trying to save the GridView, realising I Cache'd the GridView before selecting items.
        //gv_Rota = (GridView)Cache["cacheGridView"];

        //Set of the size of the array to the amount of rows * colums 
        //this will be the maximum amount of events added
        int arraysize = gv_Rota.Rows.Count * (int)Cache["columnCount"];

        //the current array item being added
        int arrayitem = 0;

        //Finally an array of ROTA_EVENTS to pass to WCF
        wsPersonnel.DC_WFM_ROTA_EVENTS[] arrayofRotaEvents = new wsPersonnel.DC_WFM_ROTA_EVENTS[arraysize];


        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_Rota.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= (int)Cache["columnCount"]; i++)
            {
                int day = row.RowIndex;
                day += 1;
                DropDownList DDL1 = (DropDownList)gv_Rota.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[i].FindControl("ddlShiftWK" + i.ToString() + "DAY" + day.ToString());

                wsPersonnel.DC_WFM_ROTA_EVENTS dcEvent = new wsPersonnel.DC_WFM_ROTA_EVENTS
                {
                    SHIFT_ID = DDL1.SelectedItem.Value,
                    WEEK = i,
                    WEEKSpecified = true,
                    DAY = day,
                    DAYSpecified = true,
                };
                arrayofRotaEvents[arrayitem++] = dcEvent;
            }
        }

        wsP.AddRota(new wsPersonnel.DC_WFM_ROTA
        {
            ROTA_NAME = txt_RotaName.Value,
            PERIOD_TYPE = 1,
            PERIOD_TYPESpecified = true,
            PERIOD_AMOUNT = ColumnCount,
            PERIOD_AMOUNTSpecified = true,
            ROTA_EVENTS = arrayofRotaEvents
        });
    }
```

Example of what the GridView looks like:

[image]

Comment: The answer to your problems is not UpdatePanels (IMHO no answer is to use UpdatePanels) I'd guess this is because you're dynamically adding controls and then when you post back the controls are no longer there because you haven't rebound them. You need to supply a lot more of your code, such as where you bind you GridView and the RowDataBound method etc

Comment: @matt_lethargic is right you need to add more code of cs page

Comment: @matt_lethargic I have supplied my C# code. Question edited. Appreciate the reply.

Comment: @EliotE123 you try GridView1_RowCreated method instead of rowdatabound event

Comment: @EliotE123 what is the code of Save button btn_AddRota_Click code ?please add code

Comment: @HiralNayak Code supplied in new edit.

Comment: @EliotE123 hey what is wsPersonnel ?

Comment: @HiralNayak It is the name of my Web Service

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop postback on button click inside the update panel then you can try this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="RotaUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_AddRota" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btn_AddRota_Click" CssClass="ButtonAdminPage" ClientIDMode="AutoID"/>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_AddRota" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried adding the bits of code you replied with, however, as I suspected, the GridView controls are still being wiped, which means the GridView must be getting reset or refreshed still. Likely because of the passing from server to client and back etc...

Comment: Code supplied for you.